# Android bluetooth pbap get request failure

Tags: android, bluetooth, obex

everyone.

I try to implement a pbap client on Android platform.

My client can get phonebook from most of android phones.

But when I connect to HTC G11, it does not work normally.

my main code is as follows:

```
mSocket = mDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(ParcelUuid.fromString(PBAP_UUID).getUuid());  //it's OK here


mSocket.connect();  //it's OK here


mClientSession = new ClientSession(transport);  //it's OK here

HeaderSet request_conn = new HeaderSet();
request_conn.setHeader(HeaderSet.TARGET, PBAP_TARGET);
HeaderSet return_header = mClientSession.connect(request_conn); //it's OK here
```

When  mClientSession.connect(request_conn) called, remote device give a response code OBEX_HTTP_OK.

It means remote device accepted my pbap connection request.

But problem come out after that.

```
HeaderSet request_get = new HeaderSet();
request_get.setHeader(HeaderSet.NAME, name);
request_get.setHeader(HeaderSet.TYPE, type);
mGetOperation = (ClientOperation)mClientSession.get(request_get);
mInputStream = mGetOperation.openInputStream();  // problem come out here
```

I send a get request to remote device but remote give a response code 211 which means 
OBEX_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE. So I cannot get phonebook from htc G11.

I try Nokia N9, it is the same with HTC G11. Nokia N9 give a response code 211 too.

But Nokia N9 and HTC G11 can transfer phonebook each other,
and both of them can get phonebook from android phones.

Android implement pbap session layer APIs in framework/base/obex

I guess HTC G11 does not use the standard android session layer APIs.

But what does it use?  what about Nokia N9?

Can anyone give me an answer or some right codes? Please help me.

I suffered from this problem a lot.
Thanks!

My email: yulf88@gmail.com

Comment: Could you please let me know how exactly you went about the process of creating a PBAP client in Android? Atleast the algorithm if possible. And where did you find the API support for this?

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could give a reply @dragonfly

Comment: @SoulRayder
Android implement pbap session layer APIs in framework/base/obex